# Accessing children as a prop in a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This may not be the Vue way to do things, but in React if I wanted to make a FancyList component I could do something like this

```
const FancyList : React.SFC<{},{}> ({children}) => (
    <ul>
        {...children}
    </ul>
);

const FancyListItem : React.SFC<{text: string}, {}> ({children}) => <li>{...children}</li>

const App = React.SFC<{},{}> () => (
    <FancyList>
        <FancyListItem>foo</FancyListItem>
    <FancyList>
);
```

This would render a `<ul>` with `<li>` children. I am trying to do something similar in Vue, but passing children around doesn't seem to be the thing to do, at least not from what I can see in the documentation. Here is what I have tried in the parent component. I have registered my FancyListItem component to the parent, and to the root. In the parent component the template looks like this

```
<ul>
  <li v-for child in $root.$children>
</ul>
```

or this

```
<ul>
  <li v-for child in children>
</ul>
```

In the root the template looks like this

```
<FancyList>
  <FancyListItem>Some Text</FancyListItem>
  <FancyListItem>Some Other Text</FancyListItem>
</FancyList>
```

In either case I can't get anything to render to the ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that's not the **Vue** way.
In vue you would use [**slots**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html):

> This allows you to compose components like this:
>
> ```
> <navigation-link url="/profile">
>   Your Profile
> </navigation-link>
> ```

Then in the template for `<navigation-link>`, you might have:

> ```
> <a
>   v-bind:href="url"
>   class="nav-link"
> >
>   <slot></slot>
> </a>
> ```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 1):

The Vue way of doing this is:

fancyListItem.vue:

```
<template>
  <li>
     <slot></slot>
  </li>
</template>
```

fancyList.vue:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <slot></slot>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Root:

```
<template>
  <fancy-list>
       <fancy-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
          {{ item.text }}
       </fancy-list-item>
  </fancy-list>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    FancyList: ()=>import('fancyList.vue'),
    FancyListItem: ()=>import('fancyListItem.vue')
  },
  data(){
    return {
      items: [
        //...items
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes slot is what I was looking for. Thank you!